# Mouseclicking on radiobutton, taking action without checking the radiobutton

Tags: c#, events, radio-button

I have 2 radiobuttons in a groupBox that i'm using to precisely tell the user what is being taken in consideration by the program.

[1]: ![the forms][1]http://puu.sh/bo5dr/e93cb1d4c9.png

What controls the radiobuttons are the textboxes on the left. I dont want the user to control the radio buttons directly, so i created a mouseclick event, and displayed a message box with a warning

```
private void radioButton271_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        // says something like the radio buttons can only be changed by geometrical properties defined in the text boxes
        MessageBox.Show("A alteração da configuração geométrica de coberturas próximas de outras mais altas só pode ser realizada através das dimensões de h e b2.");

    }
```

I was hoping that by not placing a radioButton271.Checked = true, it would not take that assumption.
But it does check the radiobutton regardless of no content in the mouseclick event.

Is this changed somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `AutoCheck` property:

```
radioButton271.AutoCheck = false;
```